# I have JS list function that works when using inline scripting but not when the HTML and JS are in seperate files

Tags: javascript, html, scripting

I'm sure this issue has come up before so sorry about that.
In short I have a HTML file with JS inline scripting that works just fine, however when I separate the HTML and JS into 2 different files (in the same folder), it stops working and I really can't figure out why.

lstore.html (HTML and JS)

```
<body>
        <h2 id="title">Local Storage - JS</h2>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Insert Accounts</legend>
            <input id="insKey" type="text" placeholder="Enter Site...">
            <input id="insValue1" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username...">
            <input id="insValue2" type="text" placeholder="Enter Password...">
            <input id="insValue3" type="text" placeholder="Enter Extra Details...">
            <button type="button" id="btnInsert">Add New Profile</button>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Local Storage</legend>
            <div id="LSout"></div>
        </fieldset>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        const insKey = document.getElementById('insKey');
        const insValue1 = document.getElementById('insValue1');
        const insValue2 = document.getElementById('insValue2');
        const insValue3 = document.getElementById('insValue3');
        const btnInsert = document.getElementById('btnInsert');
        const LSout = document.getElementById('LSout');

        btnInsert.onclick = function () {
            const key = insKey.value;
            const value1 = insValue1.value;
            const value2 = insValue2.value;
            const value3 = insValue3.value;

            if (key && value1) {
                localStorage.setItem(key, [value1, value2, value3]);
                location.reload();
            }
        };

        for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
            const key = localStorage.key(i);
            const value1 = localStorage.getItem(key);
            const value2 = localStorage.getItem(key);
            const value3 = localStorage.getItem(key);

            LSout.innerHTML += `
            <tr>
                <td>${key}:</td>
                <td>${value1}</td> <br />`;
        }

    </script>

</html>
```

only.html

```
    <head>
        <title>Local Storage</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="only.js"></script>

        <style media="screen">
            input, button {
                padding: 7px;
                height: 40px;
            }

            fieldset {
                margin-bottom: 25px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 id="title">Local Storage - JS</h2>
        <fieldset>
            <legend id="subForm">Insert Accounts</legend>
            <input id="insKey" type="text" placeholder="Enter Site...">
            <input id="insValue1" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username...">
            <input id="insValue2" type="text" placeholder="Enter Password...">
            <input id="insValue3" type="text" placeholder="Enter Extra Details...">
            <button type="submit" id="btnInsert">Add New Profile</button>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Local Storage</legend>
            <div id="LSout"></div>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

only.js

```
        const insValue1 = document.getElementById('insValue1');
        const insValue2 = document.getElementById('insValue2');
        const insValue3 = document.getElementById('insValue3');
        const btnInsert = document.getElementById('btnInsert');
        const LSout = document.getElementById('LSout');

        btnInsert.onclick = function () {
            const key = insKey.value;
            const value1 = insValue1.value;
            const value2 = insValue2.value;
            const value3 = insValue3.value;

            if (key && value1) {
                localStorage.setItem(key, [value1, value2, value3]);
                location.reload();
            }
        };

        for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
            const key = localStorage.key(i);
            const value1 = localStorage.getItem(key);
            const value2 = localStorage.getItem(key);
            const value3 = localStorage.getItem(key);

            LSout.innerHTML += `
            <tr>
                <td>${key}:</td>
                <td>${value1}</td> <br />`;
        }
```

Cheers for your time, any advice is appreciated!

Comment: You can place defer in your script tag  to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded.

Answer (score 1):

Because your JavaScript isn't wrapped with a function, it processes as soon as it is loaded. And since you load the JS file at the top of your page, the JavaScript runs before the page body has loaded. If you look in the console you will likely see an error like `LSout.innerHTML is undefined`.

An easy solution is to move the script tag in your HTML to the bottom of the body of your page.

```
<head>
        <title>Local Storage</title>

        <style media="screen">
            input, button {
                padding: 7px;
                height: 40px;
            }

            fieldset {
                margin-bottom: 25px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 id="title">Local Storage - JS</h2>
        <fieldset>
            <legend id="subForm">Insert Accounts</legend>
            <input id="insKey" type="text" placeholder="Enter Site...">
            <input id="insValue1" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username...">
            <input id="insValue2" type="text" placeholder="Enter Password...">
            <input id="insValue3" type="text" placeholder="Enter Extra Details...">
            <button type="submit" id="btnInsert">Add New Profile</button>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Local Storage</legend>
            <div id="LSout"></div>
        </fieldset>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="only.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```